# Playing .wav files in Java

Tags: java

Hello guys I am trying to develop a sound player with java  using clip .
I followed tutorials at docs.oracle.com.But i didnot understand .
Here is my code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

public class SoundPlayer{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Clip clp = AudioSystem.getClip();
            AudioInputStream is = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("1_welcome.wav"));
            clp.open(is);
            clp.start();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What is my problem is when  I run the application, nothing happens.

Comment: If your file in the right location?

Comment: If the file is in the correct location try with another file. Also check your machine's volume :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To play sound using Clip, the process need to be alive. Hence, we use a Swing application. Try this out.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SoundPlayer extends JFrame {

   public SoundPlayer() {
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      this.setTitle("Test Sound Clip");
      this.setSize(300, 200);
      this.setVisible(true);

      try {
         // Open an audio input stream.
         URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("china.mid");
         AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
         // Get a sound clip resource.
         Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
         // Open audio clip and load samples from the audio input stream.
         clip.open(audioIn);
         clip.start();
      } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new SoundPlayer();
   }
}
```

Since I'm just using this relative path `"china.mid"` with a classLoader, I have the `"china.mid"` file in the `build/classes/` directory. In Eclispe, I would have it in the `bin/` directory

Answer (score 1):

Set the volume-

```
clp.open(is);

FloatControl volume = (FloatControl) play.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
volume.setValue(1.0f);

clp.start();
```